# Returned objects and ARC in Swift

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

Let's say we have this code:

```
func getSomeString() -> String {
    let str = "Some string"
    print(str)
    return str
}
```

So I was wondering when will this `str` be deallocated by ARC? 
I think it depends on what we do with this object after getting it from this function. E.g. we have this method:

```
func anotherMethod() {
   let anotherStr = getSomeString()
}
```

thus `str` from `getSomeString()` will be deallocated after `anotherMethod()` will be called. Am I right? If no then how will this happen?

Comment: Objects get deallocated when their reference count becomes 0.

Comment: @rmaddy so in this case would they be thrown out of the memory on next pool release?

Comment: Aren't strings value types? They are not affected by ARC, right?

Comment: @Sweeper: `String` is a value type. However, the actual character *storage* is implemented as a (refcounted) class, in order to get copy-on-write behavior. (The same is true e.g. for `Array` and `Dictionary`.)

Comment: @MartinR Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>In your case, no deallocation will occur, because `String` is a value type. Value types are not affected by ARC. You can't even reference them. They are just values.</s>

Though `String` is a value type, it wraps a reference type for storage. However, since we can't override the deinitializer of the wrapped type, I'll use this code to demonstrate what happens when you return a reference type:

```
// class is a reference type!
class MyClass {
    deinit {
        print("deallocated")
    }
}

func getSomeObject() -> MyClass {
    let obj = MyClass()
    return obj
}

func anotherMethod() {
    let anotherObj = getSomeObject()
}

anotherMethod()
print("returned")
```

In the console, "deallocated" is printed before "returned". This means that by the time `anotherMethod` has returned, `obj` has been deallocated as there is no variable that refers to it.

Comment: Seems you are right. I also checked similar code (think I should have done this before posting my question) and tried putting `print("returned")` after `anotherMethod()` (got same result as yours) and after `let anotherObj = getSomeObject()` ("returned" was printed before "deallocated"). So the returned object was deallocated after it left `anotherMethod()`'s scope.